# Old adhesive over concrete

Tags: flooring

Pulling up old laminate flooring from concrete slab home. No underlayment, just old adhesive. Do I have to remove all adhesive with a solvent or can I just lay the underlayment and place new pergo on top?

Comment: floating, glue down or nail down install ?  pergo can be laminate, hardwood or vinyl - what type?